# Looking to design a cantilever support to hold up an 80kg projector

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses, structures

I need to make a support (preferably metal) for a projector to be fixed on the wall. The projector size is:

[image]

Width: **0.7m**

Length: **1.1m**

Weight: **80kg**

If anyone knows how i can solve this please let me know!
Thank you so much!

Note: This will be going to the back of the Musical theatre, the wall of the theatre is made of concrete block.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Do you *mean* "Cantilever"? The 'shelf bracket' solution which you seem to be OK with wouldn't fit that description... What space do you need to fit this into? What's the wall made of? We need more information!

Comment: @JonathanRSwift We need to fit it at a back of a theatre, it will be up 4metres from the ground. And the wall is made of concrete Brick. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I've attached an autocad of the requirement in the post! thanks

Comment: How about creating a quick design in (the free software) Fusion360 and simulating the load in the build-in FEM Simulations?
With this you can get quantitative answers without guess work.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of two L straps of either steel or aluminum similar to the attached photo. They should be 3mm thick, 20mm wide and 60cm long on each side. They have to be reinforced by a diagonal member of the same cross section welded.

They can be attached to a metal tray big enough to support the projector preferably with srapps to tie in.

The two metal angles have two holes near the top and bottom to allow for proper anchors to the wall. The anchors need to resist 160kg pull out force. Like expansive bolts for concrete or lag bolts going through the studs.
[image: bracket]

**EDIT**
After OP's edited their question and the fact that this projector is being used commercially I recommend these modifications.

- Use steel angle 4cm x 4cm by 5mm thick for legs of the bracket and the frame of the tray. Weld all corners.
- Use 3mm thick steel plate for the tray.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! - I've made the following drawing and is this what you mean? thanks

Comment: Please could you explain how you arrived 160kg for pull out force ratings of the fixings? Since there are 4 in total at the top of the brackets, moments suggest approx 40kg pull each. So is this a 4x safety factor?

Comment: @KitSithinun yes that is what I mean. and, CL22, 80kg*60cm/(2*60cm)= 40kg pull out. usually safety factor of 4 is applied to these kinds of utilities. many times operator hangs to the tray for support; leaves tools and parts on it temporarily. Therefor 4*50 =160 pull out.

Comment: @kamran Thank you. I'm going to make an order for a steel L straps. Could I use 80cm length for the strap just for extra safety? And what would be the length of x,y? Many thanks!

Comment: @KitSithinun, yes the longer the better. if you want to have a tray with 190cm depth, you'd need at least 180 cm flat leg of bracket and preferably 100cm x and 129cm y. but I don't understand why you need such a big tray.

Comment: @kamran , Thank you - big tray for service but perhaps 170-180cm in length. The x length is looking to be 208-220cm for X and 130cm for Y.  Hope this will work?

Comment: @kamran so pretty much it will be a triangle shape support - as shown in the picture attached